# How to check if two CSS files for same classes existence

Tags: css

How to check if two CSS files for same classes existence, automatically.

Comment: Do you mean programmatically at browser execution-time (using JavaScript) or using a tool to compare/merge CSS files?

Comment: Using a tool to compare CSS files for common classes so that i will try to rename the classes to avoid un necessary conflicits

Answer (score 2):

You can use a css/html/js debugger as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox.

When inspecting a specific element of a html page, the debugger shows all style properties applied to the element, why they're applied (class, id, tag, inherited) and from which css file the properties are coming.

Comment: Hi 
It shows only for a Specific element, but i want to know in one shot what are all the classes common across two different CSS files, so that i will try to rename the classes and avoid unnecessary GUI distortions

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way to do that as far as I know, but I would suggest that you use some kind of comparing tool, like BeyondCompare. It gives you a great insight of differences between two files.

Comment: ya i just thought there should be some other way, Thanks for the clarifications.